# What is @"type" in [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"type"]; Sudzc generated code

Tags: java, sudzc

I have used sudzc to generate objective C with ARC code for my existing web service (java).

1. In java, I have an object called syncResponseJB which contains an array of SyncResponseTransactionJB[] objects. When I see the code created by sudzc, it has created 3 objects. 
   a. syncResponseJB.m and h, b. ArrayOfSyncResponseJB.m and h and c. SyncResponseTransactionJB. Only C contains all the attributes/properties that I want. The ArrayOfSyncResponseJB just contains

   @implementation GRSArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB

   - (id) init
     {
     if(self = [super init])
     {

     }
     return self;
     }
   - (GRSArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB*) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
     {
     if(node == nil) { return nil; }
     return (GRSArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB*)[[GRSArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB alloc] initWithNode: node];
     }
   - (id) initWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node {
     if(self = [super initWithNode: node])
     {
     }
     return self;
     }
   - (NSMutableString*) serialize
     {
     return [self serialize: @"ArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB"];
     }
   - (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSString*) nodeName
     {
     NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString string];
     [s appendFormat: @"<%@", nodeName];
     [s appendString: [self serializeAttributes]];
     [s appendString: @">"];
     [s appendString: [self serializeElements]];
     [s appendFormat: @"", nodeName];
     return s;
     }
   - (NSMutableString*) serializeElements
     {
     NSMutableString* s = [super serializeElements];

     return s;
     }
   - (NSMutableString*) serializeAttributes
     {
     NSMutableString* s = [super serializeAttributes];

     return s;
     }

   -(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object{
       if(object != nil && [object isKindOfClass:[GRSArrayOfSyncResponseTransactionJB class]]) {
           return [[self serialize] isEqualToString:[object serialize]];
       }
       return NO;
   }

   -(NSUInteger)hash{
       return [Soap generateHash:self];

   }
2. When I do syncResponseJB., it only shows the ArrayOfSyncResponseJB and now the SyncResponseTransactionJB. I am not sure about the use of ArrayOfSyncResponseJB. I do not have an equivalent class in Java.
3. If I ignore ArrayOfSyncResponseJB and use the SyncResponseTransactionJB, it works partly. What I mean by partly is,
   My actual response XML is

   ProvisioningFor MDT or RM version 1.2.289DT_MINUTESint1440ApplicationfalseCatherinehttps://dcstest.support.xerox.com:443/download/dcs.jarTest MDT Version771911BHM000001AddServiceBillingProvisioningFor MDT or RM version 1.2.289DT_MINUTESint1440ApplicationfalseCatherinehttps://dcstest.support.xerox.com:443/download/dcs.jarTest MDT Version771912BHM000001AddServiceSupplies

But when I print the output after this line,

```
output = [deserializeTo initWithNode: element];
```

it only prints the first half of the xml and that is the only data I am getting back.

```
    po [output serializeElements]
(id) $4 = 0x06c47610 <syncResponseTrans><callType>Provisioning</callType>    <dcsBundleDescriptor><bundleDesc>For MDT or RM version 1.2.2</bundleDesc><bundleId>89</bundleId><bundleParms><bundleParmsProperties></bundleParmsProperties></bundleParms><bundleType>Application</bundleType><downloadable>false</downloadable><submitterName>Catherine</submitterName><urlOfBundle>https://dcstest.support.xerox.com:443/download/dcs.jar</urlOfBundle><version>Test MDT Version</version></dcsBundleDescriptor><orderId>77191</orderId><orderItemId>1</orderItemId><serialNo>BHM000001</serialNo><serviceActionParms><serviceAction>AddService</serviceAction><serviceActionParmsProperties></serviceActionParmsProperties></serviceActionParms><serviceName>Billing</serviceName></syncResponseTrans>
```

How can I get the second segment of the XML as well?

1. On a different angle, I am trying to see if I could use the deserializeToDictionary method. However, I do now understand What is the @"type". When I use the code as is, it returns "int"for the line below

   NSString* type = [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"xsi:type"];

Any help would be greatly useful to me.

Thanks,

Comment: The `@"foo"` notation is an Objective-C's shortcut to create a NSString whose contents is set to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks Alex. My question is, If I change that @"type" to my element name "@syncResponseTransactionJB", it returns Null. When I leave it to @"type" it returns int. I am not sure where in my XML it gets the "int" from and why is it not seeing my @"syncResponseTransactionJB" which is an element in my response xml. IN otherwords, what should I use at @"XXX" to get my elements attributes value.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10384349/1273881).
I think its SudzC's bug...