# How to access array fields in sudzc.com SOAP result?

Tags: objective-c, zend-framework, soap, nsmutablearray, sudzc

Sorry to perhaps ask stupid questions, but I'm still having issues with Objective-C syntax.
So, I've got this SOAP response from my sudzc.com generated code. It should contain a SQL SELECT result with `veh_id` and `version` as columns.

What I get as a response object is a NSMutableArray,

```
NSMutableArray* soapArray = (NSMutableArray*)value;
```

so I walk through it:

```
unsigned count = [soapArray count];
while (count--) {
   id myobj = [soapArray objectAtIndex:count];
   NSLog(@"myobj: %@", myobj); 
}
```

What I get as a printout is something like:

```
myobj: {
item =     {
    key = version;
    value = 1;
};
```

for each row of the SQL result. If this is a printout of the array element, why is there only the `version` column and not also the `veh_id` column?

How do I access the value for the key on the object `myobj` of type `id`? Do I have to cast it first?

That's the XML String returned from the Zend Soap-Server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.[myurl].com/soap" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getActiveVehiclesResponse><return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[23]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"><item xsi:type="ns2:Map"><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">veh_id</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value></item><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">version</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value></item></item><item xsi:type="ns2:Map"><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">veh_id</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</value></item><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">version</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value></item></item><item xsi:type="ns2:Map"><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">veh_id</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">4</value></item><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">version</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value></item></item></return></ns1:getActiveVehiclesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution! 
The problem lies within the deserializeAsDictionary function.
Since my Soap xml string is structured to have each database column as item - key - value - key - value etc, it adds each column under the key "item" and thus the deserializeAsDictionary function overwrites in the line

```
[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]]
```

the already added objects. In a first shot, I have added a column iterator and now call the columns "item1, item2,.." (further optimization might be necessary):

```
// Deserializes the element in a dictionary.
+(id)deserializeAsDictionary:(CXMLNode*)element {
NSLog(@"deserializeAsDictionary = %@, children: %d", element.stringValue, [element childCount]);

if([element childCount] == 1) {
    CXMLNode* child = [[element children] objectAtIndex:0];
    if([child kind] == CXMLTextKind) {
       NSLog(@"child %@ added", [child stringValue]);
        return [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    }
}

NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSInteger i = 1;
NSString *objKey;
for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
    id v = [Soap deserialize:child];
    if(v == nil) { 
        v = [NSNull null]; 
    } else {
        if([[child name] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
            objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[child stringValue]];
        } else if([[child name] isEqualToString:@"key"] || [[child name] isEqualToString:@"value"]) { 
            objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[child name]];
        } else {
            objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[child name],i++];
        }

    }

    [d setObject:v forKey:objKey];
    NSLog(@"child %@ added", objKey);
}
return d;
}
```

The result array now looks like:

```
},
    {
    item1 =         {
        key = "veh_id";
        value = 29;
    };
    item2 =         {
        key = version;
        value = 1;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.. You don't need to cast it, since it shows all the data fetched, I am facing problem that the handler method value (of id type) returns first element only.

check following code:

`...`

request = [service myServiceCall:self action:@selector(myHandlerMethod:) param:param1];

...

}

-(void) myHandlerMethod:(id)value{

NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.receivedData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// now if the "value" returned is type as some array of some object,then any arrays don't handle serialization of all the elements of the array it holds. The following code prints just outer tag. (e.g. )

NSLog("%@",xmlString);

}

Comment: The XML String looks fine - which handler method are you talking about?

Comment: any action we specify as selector in the argument when calling the service, that action method's parameter is id, which displays only first element (or none) if the type is custom array type. see the above example.

Comment: so what should I use instead to get the full array returned?

Comment: once you have the request object, you can use "request.receivedData" and then you can cast it in string (which is XML) and then you can construct your object of string or any other custom type. (see the code above. In the above code, the return type is string, so I just needed to cast the "request.receivedData" (i.e. NSData) into the NSString. In your case, cast the NSData to string, (which will be XML), then make object of the Map, by calling initWithCXMLNode and pass the cxmlnode to it, (the cxmlnode can be constructed by cxmldoc,).